# Fetching multiple rows by foreign key column

Tags: sql-server, join, self-join

I have an Address table that contains multiple addresses

```
Address: 
| Id   |   details   | ... |  
 - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - 
| 1    |  details |    ...        |
| 2    |  details |    ...        |
| 3    |  details |    ...        |
| 4    |  details |    ...        |
```

Then i have a site table, that contains address.id as FK to represent Billing or Shipping address,

```
Site: 
| Id   |   details   | Ship_Address_id  |  Bill_Address_id | ... |
 - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - 
| 1    |  details |          1           |        2          |     |
| 2    |  details |          1           |        3          |     |  
| 3    |  details |          4           |        4          |     |
| 4    |  details |          2           |        3          |     |
```

is there a way to join both the tables so that single row from site table may fetch two rows of address table, even in the case of same address of both columns. 
i was expecting to use multiple join of site with address but that is not working:

This is what i tried:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN ship.CRM_Address_Internal_Id_Ship IS NOT NULL THEN 'Ship'
        WHEN bill.CRM_Address_Internal_Id_Ship IS NOT NULL THEN 'Bill'
        ELSE '' END 
FROM Address as Adr
LEFT JOIN Site ship ON ship.Ship_Address_id = Adr.id 
LEFT JOIN Site bill ON bill.Bill_Address_id = Adr.id
```

Even if i don't use the CASE it does not fetch two rows for each address with respect to site.

Please advise.

**EDIT**
Here is the desired output table:
as in Site table we have two different ids of address table (Ship/Bill) so the result table should display two rows for each site.id
for example i'm fetching records for site.id 1 and 3 then

```
Result_Table:
| Address.ID | Address Details | TYPE | ... |
--------------------------------------------
| 1         | Other Details    | Ship | ... |
| 2         | Other Details    | Bill | ... |
| 4         | Other Details    | Ship | ... |
| 4         | Other Details    | Bill | ... |
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of your desire output?

Comment: @EdwardN Added the output, please review...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. This is an example that I implemented by **UNPIVOT**, you can take a look as references:

```
declare @address table(id int, details nvarchar(100))
declare @site table(id int, details nvarchar(100), ship_address_id int, bill_address_id int)

insert into @address values(1,'details 1')
insert into @address values(2,'details 2')
insert into @address values(3,'details 3')
insert into @address values(4,'details 4')

insert into @site values(1,'details 1',1,2)
insert into @site values(2,'details 1',1,3)
insert into @site values(3,'details 1',4,4)
insert into @site values(4,'details 1',2,5)


SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT s.id as site_id, s.bill_address_id, s.ship_address_id
    FROM @Site AS s
    INNER JOIN @Address AS sa ON s.Ship_Address_id = sa.Id
    INNER JOIN @Address AS ba ON s.Bill_Address_id = ba.Id
    WHERE s.id in (1,3)) p
UNPIVOT 
     (address_id FOR address_type IN 
      (Ship_Address_id, Bill_Address_id)
) AS unpvt
```

**Output**

```
site_id     address_id  address_type
1           1           ship_address_id
1           2           bill_address_id
3           4           ship_address_id
3           4           bill_address_id
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you're looking for `UNION ALL`, and also that your tables are backwards. I think you're looking for something more like this:

```
SELECT ship.id Site_id, CASE 
        WHEN ship.CRM_Address_Internal_Id_Ship IS NOT NULL THEN 'Ship'
        ELSE 'No Ship' END AddressPresent
FROM Site ship
LEFT JOIN Address Adr ON ship.Ship_Address_id = Adr.id

UNION ALL

SELECT bill.id Site_id, CASE 
        WHEN bill.CRM_Address_Internal_Id_Ship IS NOT NULL THEN 'Bill'
        ELSE 'No Bill' END AddressPresent
FROM Site bill
LEFT JOIN Address Adr ON bill.Bill_Address_id = Adr.id
```

I'm also wondering if you have a 'CRM_Address_Internal_Id_Bill' column that should be in the second part of the query?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but above answer seems bit more good... +1 for the simple solution